# Css - Figure placing

Tags: css, html

Hi everyone I'm fairly new to HTML5/CSS, so I'm in need of some help.

The problem is the image won't go inside the box.
It's current placement is at the bottom left of the box.
I'd like to put it in the left side IN the box and the h2 and p on the image's right side
I'm just stuck as to what I'm missing

Also, is it okay if I create an id for each of the html element? it just seems like there are too many elements, and is this frowned upon in web design? If so, what's the proper way of doing it?

Thanks very much in advance

```css
#featPost {
  padding:70px 0px 0px 51.2px;
 /* background-color: orange;*/
 }
 
 #featPost section {
 width: 750px;
 height: 261px;
 border-style: double;
 border-width: 4px;
 border-color: black;
 
 }
 
 #featPost figure {
  position: relative;
  padding-right:20px;
  float:left;
  
 }
 
 #featPost h1 {
  font-family: "Calibri", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }
 
 #featPost h2 {
  padding: 50px 0px 10px 41.5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Calibri", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  
 }
 
 
 #featPost section{
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-color: black;
 
 }
 
 #featPost p {
   padding-bottom: 150px;
   font-size: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<aside id="featPost"><article>
  
  <h1> Featured Post </h1>  

  <section>
   <h2> Essay as Easy as 1,2,3 </h2>
   <figure>
   <img src="images/example.png" width="250" height="250" alt="image of an egg">
   </figure>
   <p> What? There are rules in writing an essay?? <a href="writing_art1.html" title="Read more">Read more</a></p>  
  </section>
</article></aside>
```

Comment: Your section height is 261px and there are some element inside section and then image. Now image height is also 250px. Now if you use relative then it is quite difficult. Now if you still want same configuration for height then you need to use absolute for image then it will get inside section.

Comment: Id's are usualy used to identify elements. Styling is normally added trough the use of classes. So yes, this is frowned upon.

Comment: @user1129884, no need to add a class to an element that already has an id. Using id to style an element is fine... I don't get your point...

Comment: r u looking like this? https://jsfiddle.net/10z49k1d/

Comment: @LinkinTED Not sure if it is a coding standard or not, but in the environments I've worked in, it is certainly frowned upon to use ID's for styling.

Comment: @user1129884 Without going to much offtopic, there is nothing false with using an id for styling. If you identify a specific element with an id, imo it would be wrong to add an extra class to it... that's double work an unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to float the image to the left. I updated your code a bit:

HTML:

```
<aside id="featPost">
    <article>
        <h1> Featured Post </h1>    
        <section>
            <figure>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" width="250" height="250" alt="image of an egg" />
            </figure>
            <h2> Essay as Easy as 1,2,3 </h2>

            <p>What? There are rules in writing an essay?? <a href="writing_art1.html" title="Read more">Read more</a></p>
        </section>
    </article>
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
#featPost {
    padding:70px 0px 0px 51.2px;
    /*  background-color: orange;*/
}
#featPost section {
    width: 750px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 4px double black;
}
#featPost figure {
    float:left;
}
#featPost h1 {
    font-family:"Calibri", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#featPost h2 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:"Calibri", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#featPost p {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5apjw6cn/)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much! 
And if you don't mind, can you please explain where I went wrong? 
I did use the float:left. thanks again

Comment: Well, there was more than one 'problem'. First of, the image should be the first element inside the `section`. Then you float the image to the left. In order to keep the `section` in good shape (and not float the image out) it requires `overflow: auto`. Then I changed some margins and paddings on the `h2` and `p` to make it look as you want it.

Comment: OoooOOooo now I get itttttt
Thanks a lot @LinkinTED !!

Answer (score 0):

h2 and p tag takes full width automatically that's why you are not able to float image.